Ubuntu/Xubuntu install takes hours and won’t complete
I have an old Windows 7 Desktop (Intel i3-2120, 4gb ddr3 ram, 500gb sata Toshiba hard drive. The other day, I accidentally upset windows by deleting a profile and it wouldn’t boot. I couldn’t solve the boot issue so decided on installing a new OS. I have tried Chrome OS Flex, Then Ubuntu 24.04.1 Ltd (including older versions such as 22.04 and 20.04) and now Xubuntu 24.04 desktop. I used Balena Etcher to create a bootable usb. I plug it in and turn the machine on. I press f8 for the boot menu where I select UEFI usb option. I then select try/install and can complete all the install pages without any lag. I select this as only OS so delete discs and then install. They all stall at what seems to be the same place. They don’t crash or fail but just sit in an endless install cycle that doesn’t progress. I have ‘tried’ Xubuntu so I can be inside the desktop and the disks show as though they have been wiped because the main 500gb disk is labelled as Linux. I have run the ram checker which says that is fine. I just can’t seem to get the end of any OS install. I have been booting via a usb. Any ideas?

I am in the trial of Xubuntu and am now installing. I have just received my first error message. ubi-timezone failed with exit code 1.
I went ahead anyway but some code seems to have come up a couple of times mentioning ACPI error and ACPI bios error (bug).


Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please don't comment on your own question. Always edit your question to provide additional information. Your computer may be too old. See this article for a list of lightweight Linux distributions. They are all off topic here.

The question is without specifics for us to help with. You mention Xubuntu, but don't give release details (which is somewhat critical since two installers are involved & we don't know yet which you're attempting to use so as to provide specific help).  You also don't give details of what guide you're following, if you followed correct instructions of ISO write, what validation of steps you performed etc, as incorrect procedures can create problems in later steps, as your lack of specifics doesn't rule out user procedural errors.  Please be specific with details.

It is 24.04 Xubuntu desktop. I used Balena etcher to create the usb boot. I plugged the usb into the desktop while off and then powered the machine on. I then clicked f8 to bring up the manual boot options. The usb shows up twice one with UEFI and one without so I select the UEFI. I then select run/install Xubuntu (exactly the same process for Ubuntu too and I have tried low graphics too). Most recently, I selected the minimal install with no additional extras. I have tried to keep install minimal and without extras but with no change in outcome. User error got me into this mess!

Are you sure your computer has UEFI? Try the USB option without UEFI.

Before I press f8, it says I can press esc to go to UeFI bios… this is where I can change the boot order and select a quieter or louder fan. I am trying the non -UeFI now…

Start a live session of XUbuntu UEFI boot.
Once the boot is complete, open a terminal and run:
sudo apt install gparted
sudo gparted

From gparted, select the hard drive.
Unmount it if it is mounted.
Create a new gpt partition table.
In the free space, create a 512-megabyte partition, Efy System partition (Fat32).
Next, create a 80-gigabyte partition, ext4 system.
Create another 16-gigabyte partition, swap system.
Create another remaining partition that you plan to use for Linux, ext4 system.
Apply the changes.
Close gparted.
Close the terminal
Start the installation
Choose manual partitioning and select:
Grub by default on the hard drive.
The 80-gigabyte partition for /
The 8-gigabyte partition for swap
The remaining for /home.
Continue with the installation.
